# is it possible get values of connection from sql variable? vfp 6

Tags: connection, foxpro, visual-foxpro

there is a login in the app which does something as it

this is in production and could not be modified

```
xconec = Sqlstringconnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=laptop001;Database=Master;Uid=sa;Pwd=sa;") 

&& syslanguages es una tabla que se encuentra contenida en la BD Master de SQL Server 

xselect = "SELECT * from syslanguages" 

xenvio = SQLExec(xconec,xselect,"Micursor")
```

then always in all form or prg in fox i am using a code similar to

```
xenvio = SQLExec(xconec,xselect,"Micursor")
```

then if i do it in all modules, how can i get my connection? well i need
user,db,password,server
this is because i want to call a c# app (an exe) which is going to connect to the same server/database for do inserts. but i have only `xconect` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQLGETPROP().

```
xpassword = SQLGETPROP(xconect, "Password")
```

Or:

```
xstring = SQLGETPROP(xconect, "ConnectString")
```

and then parse xstring for the pieces that you're looking for.

This works in VFP 9, not sure about VFP 6.

Comment: xpassword = SQLGETPROP(xconect, "Password") return "", but xstring = SQLGETPROP(xconect, "ConnectString") does return the connection string, i will try to work with this

Comment: xpassword = SQLGETPROP(xconect, "Password") returned "" for me as well, but I was hoping it was because the connection I tested it on is using "Trusted Connection=Yes".